How to solve the warning EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetChanged' is obsolete?
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS0618  'EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetChanged' is obsolete: 'UnityEditor.activeBuildTargetChanged has been deprecated.Use UnityEditor.Build.IActiveBuildTargetChanged instead.'
i got this same warning on both lines:
private void OnEnable()
{ 
    EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetChanged += Update;
    EditorApplication.update += Update;
}


private void OnDisable()
{
    EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetChanged -= Update;
    EditorApplication.update -= Update;
}

if i try to change the first one as suggested to:
UnityEditor.Build.IActiveBuildTargetChanged

then i get error on this line:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0119  'IActiveBuildTargetChanged' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
another option the visual studio suggest is to add [Obsolete]
what should i do ?
the full script:
using System;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
using UnityEngine;


namespace UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput
{
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class MobileControlRig : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // this script enables or disables the child objects of a control rig
        // depending on whether the USE_MOBILE_INPUT define is declared.

        // This define is set or unset by a menu item that is included with
        // the Cross Platform Input package.

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    void OnEnable()
    {
        CheckEnableControlRig();
    }
    #endif

        private void Start()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (Application.isPlaying) //if in the editor, need to check if we are playing, as start is also called just after exiting play
#endif
            {
                UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem system = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem>();

                if (system == null)
                {//the scene have no event system, spawn one
                    GameObject o = new GameObject("EventSystem");

                    o.AddComponent<UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem>();
                    o.AddComponent<UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule>();
                }
            }
        }

#if UNITY_EDITOR

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetChanged += Update;
            EditorApplication.update += Update;
        }


        private void OnDisable()
        {
            EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetChanged -= Update;
            EditorApplication.update -= Update;
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            CheckEnableControlRig();
        }
#endif


        private void CheckEnableControlRig()
        {
#if MOBILE_INPUT
        EnableControlRig(true);
        #else
            EnableControlRig(false);
#endif
        }


        private void EnableControlRig(bool enabled)
        {
            foreach (Transform t in transform)
            {
                t.gameObject.SetActive(enabled);
            }
        }
    }
}

